# Does it have a name what John Williams is doing in these pieces (and lots of others)?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, composition, classical-music, composers

I noticed a very common thing John Williams does.
My knowledge in music theory is pretty limited.

The only thing I could name are lots of passing notes and chromaticism? - but maybe there is a special name/term for what he's doing? first piece the flute, second the keyboard and strings, third the upper strings. up and down, up and down...

excuse me if it's a heavily loaded question- maybe you can simply pinpoint what I should research? I know that maybe you could call it a sequence but it kinda doesn't help me.
https://voca.ro/1apccSSIRKNt these are three excerpts

Comment: Chromaticism is what we call chromaticism. His scores are pretty chromatic, like many film scores.

Comment: As @ToddWilcox says. In addition, these are primarily just upward and downward arpeggios.

Comment: [mild sarcasm] The common thing John Williams does, assuming you mean the film score composer, is to copy what he did before and try to make it sound different.

Answer (score 1):

These are melodic variations using arpeggios:  A simple melody is turned into a more complex melody by filling up all 16th “in between” with notes from the accompanying chord.

To avoid big jumps, the filling notes go down and back up, keeping the original melody as the top notes. The main melody can be further emphasized by accentuating these notes, or doubling them with other instruments.